# Permission error when attempting to schedule a Facebook post to a user's feed via the Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I'd like to find a way to allow users on my site to schedule Facebook posts on their personal feed ("/me/feed") via the Graph API.  Whenever I attempt this, I receive the following error message:

> (OAuthException - #200) (#200) You do not have permission to create a
>   scheduled post

Publishing a non-scheduled post works fine (I just leave out the published and scheduled_publish_time parameters), and I've also been able to successfully schedule a post to a user's individual page feed ("/pageID/feed") by providing the publish_stream, publish_actions, and manage_pages permissions.  Do I need to establish different permissions to create a scheduled post on a user's feed?  Here's a sample of the request I'm making for the scheduled post:

> https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?method=post&type=photo&access_token=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&message=Test1&picture=https%3a%2f%2fsome.jpg&published=false&scheduled_publish_time=1367301600

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to post a 'scheduled post' to a user's Timeline - this is a feature which applies to Facebook Pages, not to users profiles.