# Not able to schedule a post on Facebook User profile and Facebook group

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to schedule a facebook post on user profile and a group but api is giving me following exception:

> (#200) You do not have permission to create a scheduled post

I have following permissions from the user:

> 'public_profile','email','publish_actions',
>   'manage_pages','publish_pages', 'user_managed_groups', 'user_posts'

Do I need any other permissions from the user ?

Also, I found one [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912315/permission-error-when-attempting-to-schedule-a-facebook-post-to-a-users-feed-vi) which mentions that we can't schedule a post on user profile and user group. Is this expected behavior ? Can we schedule only on FB pages ?

Taking a look at documentation, I found schedule param only in this api, others don't have such params.

Can anyone confirm this behavior ? Also, is there is any work around to schedule a post ?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/page/feed#publish

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/feed#publish

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/group/feed#publish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in that other thread is correct, scheduled post are for Facebook Pages only. You can use a Cron Job instead, with a stored Access Token.

Since you mentioned "daily" and stuff, you may want to read the platform policy first: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

You are not allowed to prefill the message parameter, it always must be 100% user generated. And you are not allowed to autopost, every single post has to be authorized and written (!) by the user.

Comment: Okay...but how exactly will I be using the cron job ? My point is will I be running at some specified interval or daily at night but there are certain issues like there can be some miss in some schedules. How exactly do I solve such issues ?

Comment: you store the access token and you call the graph api with the cron job, it´s as simple as that. but since you mentioned "daily" and stuff, i´ll have to add some more information to my answer, stay tuned.

Comment: No, I'm not prefilling the message param. What I meant was let's say there is some post which user has scheduled for some time x. Now, what I can do is store this post in db with approprite token and when clock ticks x, I will run the cron job. But now expand this one post to multiple times for multiple users at various times. How will I run that cron job for each of the times ? I hope I make the use case clear to you

Comment: why would you want to post the same post multiple times? that would be autoposting. again, every single post must be 100% user generated. you can´t just post the same message several times, and you would never get publish_actions approved for this.

Comment: No, each of the scheduled post will be different. Only thing is they are scheduled so how can I run a cron job for that ? There is no fixed time interval for the post, right ? Should I keep running my cron job regularly waiting for any post to arrive ?

Comment: exactly. the cron job needs to check on a regular basis if the time has come to post the scheduled stuff.

Comment: I have posted my problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32189963/cron-job-for-scheduling-posting-facebook-post-any-time. Can you please take a look at it